# Problem with a Cast using Router.put with mongoDB in MERN app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I want to attach the router.put which will update the Boolean(isOn) in toggle button but firstly I wanted to try how it works and now I am facing the problem.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Buttons = require('../../models/Buttons');

// GET buttons
// This request works perfect
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
 Buttons.find()
.sort({name: 1})
.then(buttons => res.json(buttons))
});

// PUT buttons
// This one doesnt work at all
router.put('/:name', function(req,res,next) {
    Buttons.findByIdAndUpdate({name: req.params.name},         
 req.body).then(function(){
    Buttons.findOne({name: req.params.name}).then(function(buttons){
        res.send(buttons);
    });
});
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

Model of buttons has only name: String, required: true  and isOn: Boolean, required: true and data in db looks like that:

[image]

Can you tell me what did I do wrong here?

Code of Buttons modal :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const buttonSchema = new Schema ({
name: {
type: String,
required: true
},
isOn: {
type: Boolean,
required: true
}
});

 module.exports = Buttons = mongoose.model("buttons", buttonSchema);
```

Comment: please add your button modal here

Comment: The button modal has been added! :)

Comment: Need add it to async/await with try catch while you call mongodb. Since you solved it, request will process and you will catch if problem appears

Comment: I have added the async/await to the router.put but problem is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca only use `findByIdAndUpdate` when you want to update the document by matching the `_id` of the document

If you want to match the document by any other property (such as `name` in your case), you can use `findOneAndUpdate`

Write your query like this

```
router.put('/:name', function(req,res,next) {
    Buttons.findOneAndUpdate({name: req.params.name},         
 req.body).then(function(){
    Buttons.findOne({name: req.params.name}).then(function(buttons){
        res.send(buttons);
    });
});
 });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please add your id as well which you have to update in your database

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, {new: true}, function(err, model) {...
```

This error occur because  findByIdAndUpdate need id of an Object which we want to update so it shows ObjectId error. so pass your id from front end and use it in your back-end to update particulate data.

step 1 : you can create new endpoint for update-name

```
router.put('/update-name', function(req,res,next) {
  //here you can access req.body data comes from front-end
 // id = req.body.id and name = req.body.name then use it in your 
 Buttons.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { name : name }, {new: true}, function(err, model) {...

}
```

step 2 : try this endpoint /update-name and pass your data in Body from postman

Comment: I did and it still throws the CastError

Comment: if you steel confused then add your code i'll explain you.

Comment: Yeah, sure, give me few secs

Comment: I've tried this and it gave me a Body field as a response as you said but I cant type anything in there